# Why are speaker cable jack plugs sometimes fatter than intsrument cable

Tags: speakers, cable

Is there any reason why speaker jacks can sometimes have a fatter shroud than instrument cable/standard 1/4" jacks?

The reason I am asking is because I'm making my own 4 core speaker cable up with two 1/4" jacks at either end and wondered if instrument cable jacks are suitable.

Compare these two images:
[image]
[image]

The first image is 1/4" speaker cable jack plug, and the second is instrument cable. Jack plugs are not so common in home audio systems, but more common for live sound and PA systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the speaker cable is likely to be of a larger diameter and able to handle more current than standard instrument cables, thus the connection to the pins is likely to require additional space to accommodate the slightly larger cable.

Comment: To add to this answer:  I wouldn't use 1/4 inch plugs for speaker connections at all in this day and age, unless it's a guitar amp or other application that is still standardized on 1/4 inch.  Use speakon wherever possible.

Comment: You use whatever plug will go into the socket on the equipment you have chosen to use!

Answer (score 0):

6.35mm jack plugs are universal and same plug will work for either instruments or speakers

body of some jack plugs is larger to allow for use of thicker cable